# How to start tomcat project from inteliji in debug mode without 404 code with" The requested resource [/app/pdf/show] is not available

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat

I have a spring mvc project (java 8). I have a tomcat server downloaded, I copied the war file to ../apache-tomcat-9.0.85/webapps/, then in ../apache-tomcat-9.0.85/conf/server.xml
I replaced the existing port with the one I want

```
<Connector port="8112"
```

and added under

```
     <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context path="/app" docBase="app-RELEASE" reloadable="true"/>
```

If I start the tomcat server via command line with: /bin/catalina.sh run I am able to acces the resource I want, for example http://localhost:8112/app/pdf/show. But I need to debug the code, so I want to go to inteliji and add a local config of tomcat server where at url I specify http://localhost:8112/app/pdf/show, and at tab Deployment I have app:Web exploded and under application context : /app, then when I debug the configuration I receive a

```
Type Status Report
Message The requested resource [/app/pdf/show] is not available
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

even if in the logs

```
Connected to server
[2024-01-29 10:15:18,262] Artifact app:Web exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
29-Jan-2024 22:15:18.768 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[2024-01-29 10:15:18,871] Artifact app:Web exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2024-01-29 10:15:18,871] Artifact app:Web exploded: Deploy took 609 milliseconds
```

Any idea why I can't make it work from Intellij? It might be related with the settings from Artifacts in Project Structure?

Comment: If the tomcat is running fine by cmd then leave it and use remote debug in IntelliJ, you don't have to add tomcat inside Intellij: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-remote-debug.html#create-run-configurations

Comment: that's what I finally did yesterday.thanks

Comment: Have you changed HTTP port on "Server" tab as well?

Answer (score 0):

What I end up doing was to edit catalina.sh and added at the end of the file:

```
exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" jpda start "$@
```

then adding a Remote configuration in intellij with default arguments(localhost, port 8000)

then running from cmd line:

```
./catalina.sh jpda run
```